# soapui groovy execute testRunner and perform secondary test based on assertion pass

Tags: groovy, soapui, test-runner

I have a groovy test which performs some JSON slurper operations, one of these operations is to extract an id from the response. I then execute a jdbc test step from within the groovy script. My problem is this :

I need to access the assertion result from the jdbc test step - in other words, if I get a positive response from the jdbc test then I want to execute another step from within the originating groovy step.

Any suggestions on how I can do this please?

here's what I have so far :

```
for(platform in segments.platformIds) {
            if (platform.system=='ABC') {
                def platformId = "${platform.id}"
                log.info "current Id = ${platform.id}"
                testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("pass platformId").setPropertyValue("platformId", platformId)
                testRunner.runTestStepByName("Verify ID exists in DB")
                ** I want to perform another test based on the result of the above TestStep **
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

found the solution :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStepResult.TestStepStatus

myTestStepResult = testRunner.runTestStepByName("Verify ID exists in DB")
myStatus = myTestStepResult.getStatus(
                     if( myStatus ==TestStepStatus.OK)
                     ** execute the next testRunnerStep **
```